# MongoDB on Azure Cloud

Tags: mongodb, azure

Is MongoDB for Azure production ready ?
Can anyone share some experience with it ?
Looks like comfort is missing for using it for prod.

What do you think ?

> Edit: Since there is a misunderstanding in my question i will try to redefine it. 
>   The information i look into from the community is sharing an info of someone who is running mongo on windows azure to share experience from it.
>   What i mean by experience is not how to run it in the cloud(we already have the manual on 10gens faq) nor how many bugs it have(we can see that in mongo-azure jira).
>   What i am looking for is that how it is going with performance ? 
>   Are there any problems(side effects) from running mongodb on azure ?
>   How does mongodb handle VM recycling ?
>   Does anyone tried sharding ?
>   In the end, is the mongo-azure worker role from 10gens stable for using it in production ?

Hope this clears out.

Comment: You might be able to get a better answer for someone if you describe how you plan to use MongoDB for your project. Are you going to be running a single instance or scaling out to multiple nodes?

Comment: There is not much of "How you plan to use it". For now it only support single instancing (not recommended on any env.) and replication.

Answer (score 4):

A bit of clarification here. MongoDB itself is production-ready. And MongoDB works just fine in Windows Azure, as long as you set up the *scaffolding* to get it to work in the environment. This typically entails setting up an Azure Drive, to give you durable storage. Alternatively, using a replicaset, you effectively have eventual consistency across the set members. Then, you could consider going with a standalone (or standalone with hot standby). Personally, I prefer a replicaset model, and that's typical guidance for production MongoDB systems.

As far as 10gen's support for Windows Azure: While the page @SyntaxC4 points to does clarify the wrapper is in a preview state, note that the *wrapper* is the scaffolding code that launches MongoDB. This scaffolding was initially released in December 2011, and has had a few tweaks since then. It uses the production MongoDB bits (and works just fine with version 2.0.5 which was published on May 9). One caveat is that the MongoDB replicaset roles are deployed alongside your application's roles, since the client app needs visibility to all replica set nodes (to properly build the set). To avoid this limitation, you'd need to run mongos and the entry point (and that's not part of 10gen's scaffolding solution).

Forgetting the preview scaffolding a moment: I have customers running MongoDB in production, with custom scaffolding. One of them is running a rather large deployment, with multiple shards, using a replicaset per shard.

So... does it work in Windows Azure? Yes. Should you take advantage of 10gen's supplied scaffolding? If you're just looking for a simple way to launch a replicaset, I think it's fine. If you want a standalone model, or a shard model, or if you need a separate deployment for MongoDB, you'd currently need to do this on your own (or modify the project 10gen published).

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I've already checked the project. What i was interested in is if someone have experience with deploying mongodb based app on windows azure.
And what problems were introduced(if any). 
I follow the wrapper implementation on GIT and i needed an input since until a month ago i think it was still in alpha release and was not recommended for prod.

Comment: Your initial question was really vague (and not a programming question) - it's pretty open-ended. That said, I pointed out that you need to set up scaffolding. If you download and look through 10gen's code, you'll see that they deal with enumerating replica set nodes to build the set, dealing with internal ip address changes, and interfacing with diagnostics, as well as mounting drives in blob storage. These are the things you'd run into on your own. You'll also need to consider VM size, as mongodb works better with more RAM. Not sure what else anyone could possibly share on this.

Answer (score 1):

MongoLab is now offering Mongo as a service on Azure [MongoLab Blog](http://blog.mongolab.com/2012/10/azure/)

Free Demo account is 0.5 GB storage are available in [the Windows Azure Store](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/store/overview/)

Answer (score 0):

The warning message on [their site](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MongoDB+on+Azure) says that it's a preview. This would mean that there would be no support for it at a product level in Windows Azure.

If you want to form your own opinion on a comfort level, you can take a look at [their bug tracking system](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/AZURE) and get a feeling for what people are currently reporting as issues.

Comment: I follow that too. I needed some experience sharing from someone using in it in production on windows azure.